# Regex Match ONLY after x or more were found

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression for Social Security Numbers. I have a new requirement which states that the Regex should only "match" when 5 or more have been identified. I've tried several permutations but I've been unable to figure this out.

My Regex: 
    `((?!000|666|9\d{2})([0-8]\d{2}[- ]\d{2}[- ]\d{4}))`

I have tried
    `((?!000|666|9\d{2})([0-8]\d{2}[- ]\d{2}[- ]\d{4})){5,}`

Which did not work. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: When you say 'match', do you mean you want it either find five unique SSNs before it 'matches?'  With fabricated data, are you able to provide an example to work with?

Comment: same q as @hexparrot with the addition of: if yes, that sounds more like a software function than a regex pattern.

Comment: 5 or more SSN's?  So you want 5 valid SSN's in a block/line of text? You can do that but it would be simpler to iterate a simpler expression of n lines of text. ...paralleling boo's comment.

Answer (score 0):

It also looks like your pattern doesn't allow for any delimiters between SSNs. When I test it (using a version that looks for two repetitions), it works for input like `333 33 3333444 44 4444`, but it doesn't work if there's a line break / tab / space / etc between the SSNs. You may need to add the allowed list of delimiters to the end of the pattern (probably followed by a `?` or `*` character, since the last SSN in the list might not end with one).

For example, if you had commas and possibly spaces between your SSNs a revised version of your pattern might be

```
((?!000|666|9\d{2})([0-8]\d{2}[- ]\d{2}[- ]\d{4})[, ]*){5,}
```

Comment: We are using the .NET Regex engine and it does look like it will be improbable to do what I wish. The 5 or more SSN's can be anywhere in the content being searched. For example a text document, if 5 or more matches are found then show, otherwise ignore.